# Literate programming, org mode, function declaration

Tags: org-mode, literate-programming

I want to write a Literate Program with org-mode. Let's say I have the following function:

```rust
fn do_stuff()
{
    // 200 lines of code go here.
}
```

I would write something like that in org-mode:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC rust :tangle /some/path
fn do_stuff()
{
#+END_SRC

// Many more blocks of `BEGIN_SRC` go here to exlpain 200 lines of code mentioned above.
// They will have formatting, and prose between them, and headings with different nesting levels.
// The whole shebang in short.

#+BEGIN_SRC rust :tangle /some/path
}
#+END_SRC
```

Now, here is the question. I hope I will explain it well, it's kinda hard to put in words.
What do I do with the first and last #+BEGIN_SRC blocks shown above?
How do I style the function declaration with org-mode and/or Literate Programming?
It seems kind of out of place with all the “formatting, prose, headings” of the 200 lines of code mentioned above.

I need ideas please :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would use noweb to tangle the full code without necessarily presenting it all in order. That is, I would do something like this:

```
The core code is

#+name: code1
#+begin_src rust :noweb yes :tangle no
...
#+end_src

More code etc. and then, at the end:

#+BEGIN_SRC rust :tangle /some/path
fn do_stuff()
{
<<code1>>
}
#+END_SRC
```

You may need `:noweb yes` on the full code block as well.

Comment: Great idea. Thank you very much :-) Had to google what `noweb` is, I was not aware of it. I use the `nvim-orgmode` plugin, and it does not seem it supports `noweb` syntax. I've asked them and now waiting for a replay. More ideas?